# Substring in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to perform a `Substring` function on a image filename.
The name format is in "**images.png**".

I tried using `Substring` it only allow me to indicate the first character till the "n" character to perform the function.

Such that `SubString(1,6)`.

But what I want is to get any character before the `.`.

For example "**images.png**":

After the `Substring` function I should get "**images**".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `LastIndexOf` in conjunction with `Substring`:

```
myString.Substring(0, myString.LastIndexOf('.'))
```

Though the `Path` class has a method that will do this in a strongly typed manner, whether the passed in path has directories or not:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("images.png")
```

Answer (score 6):

How about using the `Path` class.

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("filename.png");
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  :) I am a **HUGE** proponent of always using the appropriate class for the job, and not trying to reinvent what already exists.

VB6 has a property on its FileSystemObject called "Title" that would  do this function.  I actually use the above as an extention method called "TITLE" on .NET's FileInfo class because I am a creature of habit.

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Function Title(ByVal fi As System.IO.FileInfo)
        Return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName)
    End Function

Answer (score 3):

In general for such string manipulations you can use:

```
mystring.Split("."c)(0)
```

But specifically for getting a filename without extension, it's best to use this method:

`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Comment: That will have a problem if the filename contains more than one "." character.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim fileName As String = "images.png"

fileName = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)

Debug.WriteLine(fileName)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "images.png";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(".")));
```